kdeconnect-indicator not working on macos 14.6.1 macbook pro m3
The app starts up, and the kdeconnect-indicator icon shows up on the menubar. On clicking configure, I see in the device name field -
macos The name org.kde.kdeconnect was not provided by any service ...
The service doesn't seem to work, no devices appear on it and it doesn't appear on other devices.

Investigating crash logs on console, I see
Termination Reason:    Namespace TCC, Code 0 
This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Allowing the app to use Bluetooth via privacy and security fixes the issue for me
